# Finite Height and Area Symmetric functions

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, summation

It has been [shown](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Fpu9Ylb9_E&t=199s) that the integral,

$$ \int_0^1 x^{-x}dx \label{eq:1} \tag{1}$$

is equivalent to

$$ = \sum_{x \ge 0}{x^{-x}} \label{eq:2} \tag{2}$$

It has also shown that this converges to a finite value.

So let's define $ f(x) = x^{-x} $, this means that

$$ \int_0^1 f(x)dx = f(0) + f(1) + f(2) \dots \label{eq:3} \tag{3}$$

Let's call functions that obey \eqref{eq:3} "Height and Area symmetric"

Are there other functions that follow this height and area symmetry while still converging to a finite value, or is this the only function that follows this rule?

Comment: Just to be clear, the property you call "height & area symmetric" is any function that satisfies Eq. 3?

Comment: Such functions form a vector space, so there are infinitely many.  (Any scalar multiple of the given function will do.)  You probably want to know the dimension of the vector space.

Comment: @aghostinthefigures Yes you are correct, I will edit the post so that is more clear.